# Remove a line that contains a word from a list

Tags: python, string, list

Having a string like this one:

```
machine1 volumename1 space1
machine1 volumename2 space2
machine2 volumename1 space1
machine2 volumename2 space2
machine3 volumename1 space1
```

I would like to remove all the lines containing one element of a list, for example:

```
list = ["machine1", "machine3"]
```

Receiving at the end something like this:

```
machine2 volumename1 space1
machine2 volumename2 space2
```

I tried with this, but it returns a list, and I would like to not change the original format of the string and I would like to use a list of machines as an input:

```
output = str([line for line in output.split('\n') if 'machine1' not in line and 'machine3' not in line])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `\n`, and `any` for `list`:

```
lst = ["machine1", "machine3"]
print('\n'.join([line for line in output.splitlines() if not any(i in line for i in lst)]))
```

Output:

```
machine2 volumename1 space1
machine2 volumename2 space2
```

Comment: The explicit list is unnecessary and slightly wasteful; `join()` can handle a generator expression.

Comment: @tripleee Well for performance I usually use the brackets, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python/9061024#9061024) out.

Comment: @tripleee haha yeah from raymond hettinger.

Answer (score 2):

Just `'\n'.join()` the list back together after filtering it.

```py
output = '\n'.join(line for line in output.splitlines() if 'machine1' not in line and 'machine3' not in line)
```

If you are explicitly examining only the first field and the whole first field, the code will be both more precise and robust and possibly even faster if you explicitly `split()` out the first field and examine only that.

```py
output = '\n'.join(line for line in ouput.splitlines()
    if line.split()[0] not in ['machine1', 'machine3'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `any` keyword to avoid any items from your list, and instead of converting to a string with `str` use `"connector".join(list)` as shown in the print function.

As a side-note, you really shouldn't use keywords like `list` to name your variables, so I've changed that variable name to `lst`.

```
output = """machine1 volumename1 space1
machine1 volumename2 space2
machine2 volumename1 space1
machine2 volumename2 space2
machine3 volumename1 space1"""
lst = ["machine1", "machine3"]

output = [line for line in output.split('\n') if not any(w in line for w in lst)]
print("\n".join(output))
```

Output:

```
machine2 volumename1 space1
machine2 volumename2 space2
```